# EC2 instance termination when operating system practises failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

Im currently learning AWS and getting my hands dirty on EC2 instances. Im wondering how i could auto terminate my instance if the operating system faces any problems such as failures. what code do i add onto the "advanced" section when setting up and configuring an instance?

Comment: If you think about it, in a critical OS malfunction situation, you can't depend on the OS to execute code.  You'll need a different strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the ec2 instance running with a role that allows the EC2 terminate instance action then you can run the following on the instance itself. It uses the the EC2 instance metadata to find it's own instance id and the AWS CLI to issue the instance terminate.

```
aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids $(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id/)
```

Alternatively if the instance is started with terminate as it's shutdown behaviour then just a "sudo halt" or "shutdown /s now" will work

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply, I know this sounds silly but where do i type that code in? Im really new to this

Comment: You would have that as a script to call when you detect OS issues. If you don't know how you might detect those failures or what you will be running on the instance I suggest you start there.